# How to add image to Mxgraph mxGeometry

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

I am currently working on a project with MxGraph, and the components that I would like to render have been created by using the mxGeometry method. I have seen many answers on stackoverflow that suggest to add an image attribute to insertVertex or addVertex methods. But I have not used such methods.
Here is a snippet from my code:

```
  class HyComp extends Component {
  constructor() {
    var w = 50;
    var h = 50;

    super(new mxGeometry(0, 0, w, h));
    this.style += "strokeColor=black;fillColor=white;";
  }

  createChildren(name) {
    let w = this.geometry.width;
    let h = this.geometry.height;

    this.createLabel(name);

    var c_in = new mxCell("", new mxGeometry(-10, 5, 10, 10));
    c_in.vertex = true;
    c_in.connectable = true;
    c_in.connectionType = "hydro";
    c_in.style =
      "editable=0;movable=0;strokeColor=blue;fillColor=white;portConstraint=west;perimeter=none;";
    this.insert(c_in);

    var c_out = new mxCell("", new mxGeometry(-10, h - 10 - 5, 10, 10));
    c_out.vertex = true;
    c_out.connectable = true;
    c_out.connectionType = "hydro";
    c_out.style =
      "editable=0;movable=0;strokeColor=blue;fillColor=white;portConstraint=west;perimeter=none;";
    this.insert(c_out);

    this.setDimensions(10, 0, w + c_in.geometry.width, h);
  }
}
```

And this is how the class `Component` looks like :

```
class Component extends mxCell {
  constructor(geometry) {
    super("", geometry);

    this.vertex = true;
    this.connectable = false;
    this.isComponent = true;
    this.componentName = this.constructor.name;
    this.userName = "";
    this.setNewId();
    this.style = "editable=0;movable=1;";

    this.setDimensions(0, 0, 0, 0);
  }
```

I have been trying to insert an image as the background for these cells for several days now, but not successful.